# How to pass tap event from overlay (onTap method )to below layer (mapview)

Tags: android

Is it possible to pass the touch event from Ovelay onTap method to the below layer which is in my case mapView? this is becouse I have a context menu on the mapview that I would like to display it.

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you consume the event in your overlay:

```
mapViewInstance.dispatchTouchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: Thanks ... the only issue is I dont have reference to "evt" from on Tap method ... Do I?

Comment: No you don't... but have you tried overriding onTouchEvent method of your overlay?